# Cauchy, Bolzano-Weierstrass, Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Why is it that if for every bounded sequence we can find a convergent subsequence (in a normed  vector space) then every Cauchy sequence converges (in this normed space)? Thanks.

Comment: In the metric generated by the nomr ||.|| , i.e., d(x,y):=||x-y||, compactness is equivalent to every sequence having a convergent subsequence. And a compact metric space is complete.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence is bounded, then continue as in the case of the real numbers: if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, then the whole sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise 1: Every Cauchy sequence is bounded.

Exercise 2: If a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$, then $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me didn't notice the cauchy v.s. boundedness link!